# Want to add more options on User database schema to premade users

Tags: mongodb, nosql

So I have this User MongoDB Schema, and I want to add other options to it. but if I do then the current users have to create a NEW Account to see the new changes. is there a way to update all the current users' schema to show the new one?

[image]